# Adding a new language to install4j

Tags: install4j

I use install4j for my application distribution. But I didn't get any information in case when I want add custom language (not from available list). For example ukrainian(UA). Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new language like that:

1. Edit the file `resource/messages/languages` and add the line

   ```
   ua=Ukrainian
   ```
2. Add the line

   ```
   languages.ua=Ukrainian
   ```

   to the file `resource/messages/messages_en.utf8`
3. Copy the file `resource/messages/messages_en.utf8` to `resource/messages/messages_ua.utf8` and translate all messages.

We are happy to ship and subsequently maintain a new translation if you send it to us.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Of course we will send you UA translation.